# Parse json array getting certain index

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to Jquery and javascript, I using ajax to upload my image and wish to get the image url, I tried getting it, I keep getting error all the time. Anyone can help me out with this? Thanks!

Error I received:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is the result after calling the url:

```
{"status_code":200,"status_txt":"OK","data":{"img_name":"nfFWV.jpg","img_url":"http:\/\/sl.uploads.im\/nfFWV.jpg","img_view":"http:\/\/uploads.im\/nfFWV.jpg","img_width":"3840","img_height":"2160","img_attr":"width=\"3840\" height=\"2160\"","img_size":"3.1 MB","img_bytes":3226508,"thumb_url":"http:\/\/sl.uploads.im\/t\/nfFWV.jpg","thumb_width":360,"thumb_height":203,"source":"base64 image string","resized":"0","delete_key":"338aa524f1654056"}}
```

and here is my code:

```
var imgfile = $('#receipt').get(0).files[0];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://uploads.im/api?upload='+imgfile,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                var htmlStr = '';
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        $.each(v.data, function(s, a){
        htmlStr +=  a.img_url + '<br />';
        });
   });
   alert(htmlStr);
            }

            });
```

Comment: data.data.img_url seems to be right

Comment: Why you need $.each?Its straightforward json.No need of $.each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access individual property of returned json,then you can do it in this way.

```
var imgObj = data.data // your response in success callback
var imgName = imgObj.img_name;
var imgUrl= imgObj.img_url;

// in this way you can access rest of property
```

There is no need of any kind of loop like `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

jquery each is not used in this way. You can use console to output your codes:

[image: the first each loop]

as you can see, you are trying to get img_url from every item of data.

you should:
[image: the right way]